# DataAnnotations With DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dataannotations

gostaria de uma ajuda.
Segue model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Data Aquisição")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public DateTime PatDtAquisicao { get; set;}
```

Estou com problema utilizando o Annotation acima, o problema ocorre quando eu envio a model para minha View de Edição, debugando o código, o valor da data é enviado corretamente para a View, porém o campo data não recebe o valor e fica Default.
Segue controller e View

```
public ActionResult Create(PatrimonioModel patrimonio)
    {
        try
        {               
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int criaRegistros = CreatePatrimonios(patrimonio.PatControle,
                    patrimonio.PatNumSerie,
                    patrimonio.PatNome,
                    patrimonio.PatDtAquisicao,
                    patrimonio.PatNumNf,
                    patrimonio.PatFornecedor,
                    patrimonio.PatLocFisica,
                    patrimonio.PatValBem,
                    patrimonio.SitCod,                        
                    patrimonio.PatTipoBem
                    );
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Listar");
        }
```

View de alteração.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatDtAquisicao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatDtAquisicao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatDtAquisicao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Método que preenche a View de alteração.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        try
        {
            var listaStuacao = LoadSituacaoBem();
            var data = LoadPatrimoniosEditar(id);
            PatrimonioModel patrimonios = new PatrimonioModel();
            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                patrimonios.PatCod = row.PatCod;
                patrimonios.PatControle = row.PatControle;
                patrimonios.PatDtAquisicao = row.PatDtAquisicao;
                patrimonios.PatFornecedor = row.PatFornecedor;
                patrimonios.PatLocFisica = row.PatLocFisica;
                patrimonios.PatNome = row.PatNome;
                patrimonios.PatNumNf = row.PatNumNf;
                patrimonios.PatNumSerie = row.PatNumSerie;
                patrimonios.PatTipoBem = row.PatTipoBem;
                patrimonios.PatValBem = row.PatValBem;
                ViewBag.SitCod = new SelectList(listaStuacao, "SitCod", "SitNome", row.SitCod);
                patrimonios.SitNome = row.SitNome;
            }
            return View(patrimonios);
```

Se eu remover o Annotation, a data é exibida corretamente.
Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você não apresentou a view nem a controller de edição... coloque o código na pergunta e não um print da tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema acima já solucionado alterado o DataFormatString no Annotation.

```
    [Display(Name = "Data Aquisição")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime PatDtAquisicao { get; set;}
```